# How to render fields with ->view() in a render array table?

Tags: theming

I am building a table in my build function of a block and want to render formatted field values or entities with the `->view();` method in a cell of my table.

As described here:
https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-9-fields-right-way

I have a value like this:

```
$cell_value = $entity->field_name->view();
```

It outputs a render array. But when I put it in the table like this. Nothing shows up.

```
  $header = [
      'col1' => t('COL1'),
      'col2' => t('COL2'),
    ];
    $rows = [
      ['test col 1', $cell_value],
      ['test col 1', 'test'],
      ['test col 1', 'test'],
    ];
    return [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
    ];
  }
```

But when I render it like this:

```
return $cell_value;
```

I see a rendered value.
Is there a way to render it in a table and how?
Currently I am making every field manually which is very time consuming.

Comment: Why not make a table field formatter or theme the host entity with a view mode?

Comment: At a glance I think you should have `['test col 1' => $cell_value],` and do the same for the other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it helps to put the render array in a `data` subkey:

```
$rows = [
  ['test col 1', ['data' => $cell_value]],
  ...
```

Comment: Wow! thanks it works, so happy! Had to finish something soon, this saves me allot precious time and headache.